# What are some good plug-ins or software for cleaning up audio

Tags: pro-tools, sound-editing

I'm Ryan. I just started getting jobs being an audio freelancer, doing little short films and interviews. But I can across a problem I got a little embarrassed with. I was sent audio files from someone, and the audio files were recorded very low, and there was a loud refrigerator in the back of the vocals. I tried every thing I could think of in pro tools. Only thing I found that was Soundsoap 3 cleaned it up. But it was only a demo so I couldn't export the files.

My question is, what do you guys use to clean up audio files? I'm on the hunt for new plug-ins, and/or if I have to maybe a new software. Soundsoap 3 seemed nice, and so does, isotope rx3 seems very nice also. Any advice would be wonderful, and thank you in advance.

I'm also kinda of on a budget.

Answer (score 3):

Izotope RX is probably what you'd want.  You can start with basic if your on a budget and then upgrade to advanced later.
It has plugin components as well as a standalone version.
It and Cedar are pretty much the standards at this point.
Multiband compression/expansion or something like the Waves WNS or W43 can help for a constant  noise.

Answer (score 0):

My choice of noise reduction at the moment is [Voxengo Redunoise](http://www.voxengo.com/product/redunoise/). Not as versatile as RX, since it only does noise reduction, but it's very easy to get good results with it and doesn't cost much.

Unfortunately it's only available as 32bit VST and doesn't work well with bridges.

More complete budget solution would be Acon [Restoration Suite](http://acondigital.com/products/restoration-suite/). I didn't like it's noise reduction as much as Redunoise's, but if you need declipping and declicking you could give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

More "constant" noise can be put out of pressence with eq-notches. (Automate cutoff if needed)

Also try expanding the file. Use the sidechaine too Filter out the strong Vocal frequencys! Gl

If this does not help -> rx3 or waves Denoise Plug ins!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on a budget I would recommend Adobe Audition. Adobe has an older version for free on their website.

Izotope rx3 is what I'd recommend spending your money on. It sounds a lot more natural with a lot less artifacting!

Multiband expansion mentioned by others is a powerful way to suppress noise as well. Use a plugin like Waves C4 or the C6. It has a few noise reduction presets to get you started. Expansion can really help on distant and reverberant dialogue. I always try some sort of expansion before I dive into rx3, but it usually ends up a combo of both with some EQ notching.